# I need to write a JS regex that starts with a lowercase letter and followed by lowercase letters and numbers. Length can be of 25 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Example -

Strings should be acceptable - a9, aa, aaaa9 , aaaa9aa

Strings should not be acceptable - 9a, 99a

So far, I have the regex -

```
/^([a-z][0-9]{1,25}$)/
```

But with this, a9a, aaaa9, aaaa9aa case is failing. Please correct.

Comment: @B001ᛦ /^([a-z][0-9]{1,25}$)/

Answer (score 2):

I believe this works.

`^[a-z][a-z0-9]{1,24}$`

The `^[a-z]` is important because you specifically want lowercase letters in the front.